# Is there a Stack Exchange site for just issue solving without reputation limits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange section or site for issue(s) solving and with no reputation limit on question's acceptance, so people could ask about rare problems being watched or reviewed?

E.g., "What are the reasons for iwatch, on Linux distribution (Ubuntu), notifying about create events listing a "//.ismount-test-file", that is not to be found on this root file system root directory?"

From my experience, such a question (given, its not an absolute suitable example of a rare content question) will not get very much interest and maybe even negative or no upvoting, because only a few will have experience with this particular difficulty or problem or even understand what could be a cause for or reasoning for this tool's output? (Trying to solve this question's difficulty in comments ended with no explanation or solution, so far. That's comprehensible, because SE Meta is no expert site therefore and it seems that references for solving were not attempted or successful. This, describing experiences and reality somewhat supporting following suggestion for feature-request:)

I would recommend creating a (or an experimental testing phase) Stack Exchange site, with asking questions for being solved for users that did reach (a state of 'question on hold' or) question ban (for several reasons). Maybe this site is called (with a supportive tone) Stack RareContentCollector and limited to one additional question once a week accessible for users with question ban from every Stack Exchange site.
I don't see this initial attempt for another Stack Exchange site being an exact duplicate to suggested question/answer for less strict rules on each Stack Exchange site or another Stack Exchange site for 'questions on hold', but for (also) question banned users with a weekly cadence for a chance of asking (for to improve or solve difficulties). We agree on thinking that site being a pool from different topics (SE sites) and interest areas meeting on that site for just asking a question for to solve difficulties. It's close in meaning and suggestions, but suggested duplicate doesn't consider the problem of question banned users (what includes the possibility, that a question ban can be caused from a summary of years old questions, off-topic starter questions, 'ahead of mainstream' or rare content questions (therefore possibly no answers), that are potentially more inclined to neutral or even negative voting, because of lacking a wider identification base with voters or deleted by Community bot and therefore hidden from voting and review.)

[Stack Exchange Meta Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour) advised:
"Be part of the community that decides how the sites work"
"Ask about...
Specific issues with the software that powers the Stack Exchange network
Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered using this software"
"Any question that has to do with the Stack Exchange family of communities is fair game."

Just a side note to a now recognized limitation:
"On posts tagged feature-request, voting can indicate agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself."

If the feature-request tag would be removed, will votings showing disagreement/agreement be adjusted, because there's a change in purpose for voting?

Thanks for contribution to brainstorming on that difficulty.

Comment: A problem being rare is irrelevant to whether it will be on-topic and acceptable. Downvotes are given because the question is not understandable because of its writing, not because the users are un-expert. More likely, you're just not asking a question that fits on Stack Exchange, and there is no site on the network that takes content purely because nobody else will. For good reason.

Comment: @Nij "A problem being rare is irrelevant to whether it will be on-topic and acceptable." Yes, but it seems often being a reason for downvoting, if people feel it's not related to their interests or difficulties. From my experience (being blocked on further questions, because improving rare questions will not get down-voters back correcting their votings after several days or weeks)

Comment: Also, quite likely you haven't spent a lot of debugging effort if that is your problem formulation. Are the double slashes significant? Does it generalize to other file names of the same form? If so, is the dot significant?

Comment: @tripleee a current available output from ```iwatch -v -r -e create,modify -x '/sys|/dev|/proc|/media|/mnt' /``` is "[ 1/Jul/2023 15:54:44] IN_CREATE //.ismount-test-file". This file is not to be observed in root file system or `pwd` of iwatch console directory with 0.1s resolution.

Comment: I really doubt there are (m)any users  that downvote questions solely because they are rare, it's much more likely that it gets downvoted because it's off-topic, badly worded, ... And I know that I (and I guess don't give much interest in reputation, so what you ask for is basically any site in the network, unless you want a place to ask poor questions, then the answer is that there is obviously no such site.

Comment: I would recommend a site, maybe called GarbageCollector, where questions could be asked, independently of previous acceaptance of a users questions, because of rare interest induced down-voting, if this satisfies all strict quality driven supporters. It's about asking a questions (that might not be well received, because it's for rare audience, but might be important to solve, if researched here on "GarbageCollector". And see how users would accept and utilize this option and possibilities there. Worth a try?)

Comment: That has been proposed many times, but I could not find an exact duplicate, so I chose one which seemed close enough. Maybe review the most downvoted questions on this site to look for a better duplicate. The idea has many flaws, but this comment box is too small to recap them all.

Comment: @Henrik supports the community "badly worded" is a difficulty for all non-native speakers, please all 'relax' somewhat on this, if intention of a question is understandable. My experience seems different on rare content or very specific questions (e.g. FPGA bootloader difficulty) with review over some month and few years. Poor is not rare (to the interest of the most common groups or mainstream, rare problems with impact need solving also. Would You agree on that?)

Comment: ... But in so many words, why do you imagine anyone would want to spend their time reading and trying to answer atrociously horrible beginner questions in a festering cesspool of junk?

Comment: I'm really struggling to see any value whatsoever in a dumping ground for poor questions… without limit. There are limits precisely so that people who consistently post poor questions are stopped in their tracks.

Comment: @tripleee "has been proposed many times", that might had originated a standardized response for to refer to? Your example site suggests relaxation to rules for new users, not that much for rare or very specific content on a different "RareContentCollector" site (well, a better name to be found, if all agree)? I need some time thinking about Your example site and suggestions, thank You.

Comment: "Badly worded" obviously means "to the point that we can't understand the problem articulation". In my experience, the tolerance for grammatical errors is high as long as they don't impede understanding, and many such questions get edited into idiomatic English fairly quickly if they are otherwise worth keeping.

Comment: @Tetsujin "consistently post poor questions are stopped", only 1 additional badly received/accepted, rare content (susceptible to down-voting) question once a week? This seems being a reasonable time frame? Allowed for users connected for years to Stack to delete own 'newbie' questions from 1st year (with high down voting or neutral voting), that are obsolete, wrong Stack site/off-topic and low quality? I do understand Your concern and support to quality questions (and answers).

Comment: You just can't get Q-banned for one or two bad questions, so it is not that you ask a question about a rare problem, but a matter of ongoing low quality and clarity. Refusing to do anything to fix that and complaining here instead will lead to exactly the outcome you're experiencing. Your comments here indicate the same: incoherence and a lack of clarity.

Comment: You seem to have several conceptual issues here. 1) you equate rare with poor. Rare is fine. Ask it well & you might get the odd upvote. Ask it badly & you will get downvotes. Your question here, for instance, is badly worded.  2) Can I be exempt from established practice & have somewhere my precious, badly-written questions will not be punished? Answer: No. There are already rate limits in place - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide This is how it already works for users not additionally limited by asking too many poor questions.

Comment: 3) Can I delete old questions or answers? Rules for deletion are already well-established - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: @Nij "incoherence and a lack of clarity", i'm sorry for that. Expressing this difficulty and suggesting a site solving question limitations costs me (at the moment) 22 reputation on Meta Stack Exchange (from anonymous users that don't like or don't understand my concerns) and because of not being expert for all site details, just wanting ask a (rare problem) question, after badly received questions over years or ones years old. That are Your rules? Yes.

Comment: *"from anonymous users that don't like or don't understand my concerns)"* you have **FIFTEEN COMMENTS** telling you what the problems are with your posts. Your concerns are, at this point, somewhat irrelevant, because either they are in favour of things that the site and community do not want or need, or they are never going to resolve the situations you evidently don't want to be in.

Comment: [@Nij "FIFTEEN", not sure if You are summarizing a opinion of each individual of a group of 15. I doubt that.]

Comment: "From my experience, this question will not get very much interest [...] because only few will have experience with this particular difficulty or problem or even understand what could be a cause for or reasoning for this tool's output" - I fail to see what this has to do with your suggestion of a site for question-banned users. Questions don't get downvoted because nobody knows the answer, and users don't get question-banned for posting such questions. Users get question-banned for asking low-quality or off-topic questions that get closed or deleted.

Comment: If nobody on regular Stack Exchange knows the answer to your question, what makes you think the question-banned users on your hypothetical site are going to know the answer?

Comment: @F1Krazy, see from Stack rules this is a low-quality question, because it is on a -14 reputation (at the moment). On a "hypothetical site" question-banned users could post a question once a week (and tag), that is not necessarily another 'low-quality' question. Moderation on that site could be reduced effort, also, because every Stack user knows/'would be informed on entrance', that questions there are from question banned users and potentially 'low-quality', but seen and maybe answered for solving a difficulty? If solved a difficulty, kept, otherwise automatically deleted after 1-3 month?

Comment: @F1Krazy "posting such questions", it's enough getting no answer and staying with no up-vote for getting question-banned (with additional bad received newbie questions from start) - just my experience and maybe wrong on that generality(?)

Comment: Getting no answers and no upvotes does indeed contribute towards getting question-banned, but generally speaking, they're not enough on their own. It takes multiple downvoted and deleted questions (which may well be the newbie questions you were referring to) to tip you over the edge.

Comment: From what I understood from the problem distributed throughout the entire post, it doesn't seem to be a case of a rare question. It appears to me that you are simply asking a question that would be adressed to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com) site on Stack Overflow and are suffering the consequences for non posted it in the specialized community intended to address this type of problem.

Comment: Imagine for a minute you got your wish & you could post to "Questions by people who are question-banned elsewhere.SE". What's your audience? No-one. It's just going to be a rusting junkyard in one quiet corner of the internet. No-one is ever going to go there to answer questions. They know all the questions will be poor ones, specifically because they will all have been written by people currently question-banned for a consistent record of poor questions. It's a self-fulfilling prophesy.

Comment: @beyondtime: It has already been explained what "badly worded" meant. And I'm also not a native speaker of english, so I know there can be issues (people have pointed out minor mistakes I've made). And yes, *rare* issues deserve an answer, but that doesn't change the fact that it shouldn't be presented in a poor question, and while an issue might deserve an answer, sometimes you have to realise that noone can help.

Comment: Having a place like you describe would be virtually indistinguishable from opening a text file on your local PC and writing your question there, saving it, and occasionally going back to look at it. If you find it satisfying to have written your question down somewhere, then by all means go ahead and do that - because as far as I can see that will be the only outcome.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there's a Stack Exchange section for issues solving and with no reputation limit on question's acceptance, so people could ask about rare problems being watched or reviewed?

Funny thing is people *love* rare and unusual problems. Exotic stuff is *exciting*. No one gets excited by pigeons, but you see ONE eagle, and whoa.

> "What are the reasons for iwatch, on Linux distribution (Ubuntu), notifying about create events listing a "//.ismounted-test-file", that is not to be found on this root file system root directory?"

From the title alone - the problem is that its broad. That's the *actual* problem this is causing? Do you want to find what's causing //.ismounted-test-file or is this causing a problem?

Its not a rarity problem, its a "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." Problem.

With an *actually* rare and uncommon problem its an issue of subject matter expertise, and writing out a question where one can understand the unique aspects of the problem and hopefully replicate the working bits.

> Is there's a Stack Exchange section for issues solving and with no reputation limit on question's acceptance, so people could ask about rare problems being watched or reviewed?

That's a hard sell, since for many folks the 'model' is the important thing.  It almost feels like you'd be better served in a forum, discussion board or mailing list. This seems less about rarity, than trying to get the benefits of getting many eyes without the constraints of voting, *but* that would mean some benefit for answerers over say Stack Overflow or Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for Your engagement. The specific example already started being worked on in the comments, so it would be possible answering or solving the problem here, because people know the difficulties, but the system does not allow me to ask on Stack Overflow again, because of reputation difficulties for not well received questions, hardly or impossible to improve or delete? `"It almost feels like you'd be better served in a forum, discussion board or mailing list."` Yes, and i don't like down-voting without reasoning within a questions content, only for to express dislike of an idea to discuss.

Comment: specific to the example: "causing //.ismounted-test-file", if someone could tell me, what is causing this '.ismounted-test-file' on this '//' location and  why this file is not on '/.ismounted-test-file', what would be most obvious directory, well then, i'm satisfied with a support idea for software questions (Stack Overflow) being supportive and constructive (what's the reason for a voting system for Q/A and quality related for knowledge and solutions to difficulties?)

Comment: I think a significant part of your issue is you don't write well. I don't mean syntax & grammar, they're fine, I mean conveying the idea well. Your three comments here are little more than stream-of-consciousness. There really is no single idea in any of them that anyone could focus on. It's just rambling. Long sentences that start off in one direction & end in another with no coherent aspect to them. Your last comment, for instance, is just two sentences. It just meanders, run-on after run-on. No-one will follow that train of thought to any rational conclusion. **Be clear. Be Concise.**

Comment: " because of reputation difficulties for not well received questions, hardly or impossible to improve or delete?  is really the problem. Also, as a fairly well educated critter - I'd *rather* write down for readability or stop to explain than try to try to be too clever and confusing the poor reader

Comment: @beyondtime note that the question is not on topic on [so] anyway since it isn't about programming. It would, however, be on topic on [linux.se], [ubuntu.se] and [su] off the top of my head.

Comment: @terdon on strike You're referring this "What are the reasons for iwatch, on Linux distribution (Ubuntu), notifying about create events listing a "//.ismount-test-file", that is not to be found on this root file system root directory?" not suitable for Stack Overflow? Solving the problem could require programming (or compiling, i don't know yet), but yes, initially it might be solved with limited distribution configuration efforts (AskUbuntu specific, Unix&Linux more generally) or other tools interacting. Since iwatch seems being a perl script, it's related to a perl tool difficulty.)

Comment: @beyondtime yes, [so] is for writing your own code. Your question is about how an existing tool behaves, so it isn't about programming at all. Even if the solution might require modifying the Perl script, that is still completely on topic on both [linux.se] and [ubuntu.se]. These sites are about using and administering *nix systems, and  that very much includes tweaking Perl scripts.